# Empty all array values except two values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently developing Yahtzee game in java and I got stuck with the re-roll dice logic.

I have an array with the 5 random dice, the player can decide which die he wants to keep and the other dice to re-roll.

For example, the player decided to keep the die with side 4 and the die with side 3. What I'm doing is creating a new array and storing only the selected dice.

```
randomDice: [5, 1, 3, 1, 4] 

selectedDice: [0, 0, 3, 0, 4]
```

After that, the player rerolls only the dice he didn't select. And should get something like that:

```
randomDice: [4, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```

The reason I'm using two arrays is that the RandomDice is actually JButtons which later I loop.

Here is some code snippet to give an idea:

```
rollDice.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

                JToggleButton diceButtons[] = new JToggleButton[loadGame.getRolledDice().length];
                int selectedDice[] = new int[loadGame.getRolledDice().length];

                diceBox.removeAll();

                for(int i = 0; i < loadGame.getRolledDice().length; i++ ) {
                    // make new button name
                    diceButtons[i] = new JToggleButton(String.valueOf(loadGame.getRolledDice()[i]));

                    int dieKey = i;
                    diceButtons[i].addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {
                            if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){

                                selectedDice[dieKey] = Integer.parseInt(diceButtons[dieKey].getText());

                                System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(selectedDice));

                            } else if(ev.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.DESELECTED){

                                selectedDice[dieKey] = 0;

                                System.out.printf(Arrays.toString(selectedDice));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    // add button to panel
                    diceBox.add(diceButtons[i]);
                };
```

My question is how I can achieve the re-roll and keep the previously selected dice sides?

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: Yes: My question is how I can achieve the re-roll and keep the previously selected dice sides?

Comment: Can you post some more code? The issue is kind of obscure. We don't know what types any of these variables are.

Comment: Just iterate through the array and only re-roll a new value if the current value is 0?

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? I updated the code snippet I hope is more clear now.

Comment: Hello, if you know the blocked positions and these are in an array, you can iterate through the dice positions and generate values for these positions. Example: `Random r = new Random();
int limit = 5;
int[] keep = {2, 4}; // blocked positions in prefilled array
int[] prefilled = {0, 0, 3, 0, 4};
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    int current = i;
    if(Arrays.stream(keep).noneMatch(b -> b == current)) { // Check, if position available in array
        prefilled[i] = r.nextInt(5) + 1; // fill the array
    }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get all selected dice indices in array, and on re-roll simple add:

```
if(selectedDices.contains(i, true)) return;
```

For others - change JToggleButton value to new value.